# How does undersampling help classification of imbalanced data set?

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes

In a 2 class classification and a dataset with majority Class 0 and minority Class 1, undersampling of the majority class (Class 0) is sometimes used to aid in classifying the minority class (Class 1). This is done when Class 1 is object of focus, such as in fraud detection.

How does this help to identify Class 1 better?

1) Does it help because the algorithm becomes more sensitive to Class 1 instances?

How does it do so?
 a) Is it because predicting Class 1 is independent of 
    predicting Class 0?

b) Is it because predicting Class 1 is not mutually exclusive
    in predicting Class 0?

Comment: It can help you, because the dataset becomes more balanced, but it is also a risk, as some important features for difference in the two classes can be excluded. Another method to do handle inbalanced datasets is: Smote

Comment: @PV8 SMOTE can lead to overfitting. I think the ideal method would be to first cross-validate the data and thereafter apply undersampling or oversampling methods to ensure adequate class distribution.